# Reading large number of files and merging them in the shell

Tags: shell

I am reading values of different variables from a SLHA file and putting value of each variable in a dedicated file using shell script. I have around 50 such variables so 50 data files are generated. A portion of the code is given below-

```
 grep "        25" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mh.out
 grep "   1000001" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mdl.out
 grep "   2000001" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mdr.out
 grep "   1000002" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mul.out
 grep "   2000002" SPheno.spc|head -1|awk {'print $2'} >> mur.out
 .
 .
 .
```

I want to merge all of these `.out` files from the shell itself in a single grand file. I tried to use c++ but opeing such large number of files does not appear efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what operating system you use but it seems it's some kind of `Unix`. As such you might be able to do what you want just with `cat` like that:

```
$ echo 3 > mh.out
$ echo 4 > mdl.out
$ echo 5 > mdr.out
$ echo 6 > mul.out
$ echo 7 > mur.out
$ cat *out > MERGED
$ cat MERGED
4
5
3
6
7
```

I don't know what's real contents of your `.out` files so I made it up.